# How do i go from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-intent

I have a Main class and a HelloWorld class. I have created a button in Main.xml when i click this button it should start HelloWorld activity. When i execute it, It force closes when i click the button. Log cat also given below.

Main.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView map;
long start;
long stop;
int x, y;
GeoPoint touchedPoint;
Drawable d;
List<Overlay> overlayList;
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
int lat ;
   int longi; 





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(Main.this, "you clicked on button!",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, HelloWorld.class);
    startActivity(intent)
        }
    });

    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mv);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);

    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinn);

    //Placing pintpoint
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();

    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if (location != null){
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() *1E6);
        longi= (int) (location.getLongitude() *1E6);



        GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
        CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
        custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Couldnt get provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }





}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this );
}


    @Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



class Touchy extends Overlay{
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        start = e.getEventTime();

    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        stop = e.getEventTime();
        x = (int) e.getX();
        y = (int) e.getY();
        touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);

    }
    if (stop - start > 1500){
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Pick Option");


        alert.setButton("Hello", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
                CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);



        }
        });
        alert.setButton3("Get Address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try{
                List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 , 1);
                if (address.size() > 0){
                    String display = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){

                        display += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
            }
        }});
        alert.setButton2("Toggle View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (map.isSatellite()){
                    map.setSatellite(false);
                    map.setStreetView(true);
                }else{
                    map.setStreetView(false);
                    map.setSatellite(true);
                }
            }
});
        alert.setButton("Place a Pin", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
                CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);

            }


        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

        return false;
    }

}



public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lat = (int) (l.getLatitude() *1E6);
    longi = (int) (l.getLongitude() *1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
    CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    overlayList.add(custom);

}




public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "you clicked on button![enter image description here][3]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

Log cat

```
04-04 22:56:21.623: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x4001d800)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mehul.googlemaps/com.mehul.googlemaps.HelloWorld}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   Method)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:    Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.mehul.googlemaps.HelloWorld.onCreate(HelloWorld.java:20)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 11 more
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 21 more
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of   MapActivity.
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:282)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 25 more
```

If anything else is required let me know.. will put it up.

Comment: checkout your xml layout file

Comment: if you have not get solution then edit post with xml's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logcat you have to watch out for

```
04-04 22:56:21.703: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of   MapActivity.
```

What you can do is, create a test.xml file with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hellotv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and in your HelloWorld do `setContentView(R.layout.test);`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of   MapActivity.
```

The error message seems pretty clear to me. Your activity that includes a `MapView` needs to derive from `MapActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

In Helloworld class you are using setcontentView(r.layout.main);

and your main.xml has map view.

and from the below line in your code

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity
```

you are extending to activity so the app is getting crashed.

use below line instead of above

```
public class HelloWorld extends MapActivity
```

or create a new layout file for HelloWorld.java..

Thats it...

Comment: Its giving error on rest of the code if i change from Activity to MapActivity